# ssh directory disappears after `mv ssh .ssh`

Tags: directory, mv, dot-files

I was in user home directory , and wanted to rename the ssh folder into .ssh folder. 
I tried this.

```
rachit@DESKTOP-ENS2652:~/ssh$ ls
some-machine  some-machine.pub
rachit@DESKTOP-ENS2652:~/ssh$ cd ..
rachit@DESKTOP-ENS2652:~$ ls
ssh
rachit@DESKTOP-ENS2652:~$ mv -R ssh .ssh
mv: invalid option -- 'R'
Try 'mv --help' for more information.
rachit@DESKTOP-ENS2652:~$ mv ssh .ssh
rachit@DESKTOP-ENS2652:~$ ls
rachit@DESKTOP-ENS2652:~$ ls
```

After doing this, my ssh folder competely disappeared. Its no big deal I can create another one , but am not able to get my head around what did I do wrong , and why is it wrong.
I am trying out things on WSL ( Windows subsystem for linux). Basically ubuntu on windows 10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This

```
mv ssh .ssh
```

could move `ssh` into an (already existing) **`.ssh`** directory.

Do this

```
mv .ssh/ssh ./
```

to put it back.  You would have seen `.ssh` if you had done

```
ls -la
```

If `.ssh` did not already exist, then

```
mv .ssh ssh
```

will make it "appear" when you do just

```
ls -l
```

Comment: Unless `.ssh` didn't exist before hand, in which case it's now just called `.ssh` and `ls -a` will show it.

Comment: I suppose so...

Comment: Just while you typed the answer , I googled for search command and found that the files in ssh folder were indeed moved to .ssh/ssh, which means `mv ssh .ssh` moved the entire ssh folder inside .ssh, Once I put the ssh folder back in place with the command you said , I guess I should do `mv ssh/* .ssh` to move only contents of ssh into .ssh. ( Please correct me if wrong)

Comment: yes - that sounds right.  The question seemed to say you wanted to keep a `ssh` folder in addition to the `.ssh` folder.  It helps to put a trailing `/` on things that you assume are folders (just in case they are only files...).

Comment: Thanks , the last line really helped. I was just curious about that.

Answer (score 3):

By default files and directories beginning with `.` are *hidden* from view.  Standard commands like `ls` and shell globbing such as `*` will not match them.

For `ls` you can show *dot files* with `-a` (or `-A` to hide `.` and `..`).

So, for example:

```
$ ls
$ touch foo
$ touch .bar
$ mkdir .baz
$ ls
foo
$ ls -a     
.  ..  .bar  .baz  foo
$ ls -A     
.bar  .baz  foo
```

So now when you did `mv ssh .ssh` one of two things may have happened:

1. If `.ssh` didn't exist before then you did exactly what you wanted.  You can do `ls -a` and see it.
2. If `.ssh` *did* already exist then you renamed it to `.ssh/ssh`.

In both cases you can do `ls -a .ssh`

In you see the files `some-machine` and `some-machine.pub` then you did what you wanted; you were in case 1.

If, instead you see `ssh` (maybe amongst any files that were there previously) then it means you were in case 2.  You can fix this with:

```
mv .ssh/ssh .
mv ssh/* .ssh/.
rmdir ssh
```

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed answer. I already marked the other one as answer.You guys made me feel welcome to the forum.

Comment: Also I think the second point in your answer is incorrect. The .ssh folder already existed , however it wasn't renamed. Instead the entire ssh folder was moved inside .ssh folder. Confirmed this by doing `ls -a` on .ssh and it showed the existing files.

Comment: Right, but if you did an `ls .ssh` then among the existing files you would also have seen an `ssh` directory.  It would have moved the `ssh` directory inside `.ssh` but not deleted any previous files.  I edited the answer to hopefully make that clearer.

Comment: Yeah .. thats what happened. Thanks. Now after undoing with the first command , I guess I can also do `mv ssh/* .ssh` or `mv ssh/* .ssh/`. ( Figured this from the comment in other question ). Now what would be the difference between `mv ssh/* .ssh/` and `mv ssh/* .ssh/.` (Mentioned in your answer)

Comment: There's not really any difference, in this case, between `mv ssh/* .ssh/` and `mv ssh/* .ssh/.` - they both refer to the same directory.  The `.`  entry in a directory means "this directory".  Both `mv` commands are ways of ensuring `.ssh` is a directory and not a file.